# In ArangoDB, will querying, with filters, from the neighbor(s) be done in O(n)?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

I've been reading Aql [Graph Operation](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphOperations.html) and  [Graphs](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html), and have found no concrete example and performance explanation for the use case of [SQL-Traverse](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Traverse.html).

**E.g.:**

If I have a collection *Users*, which has a *company* relation to collection *Company*

Collection *Company* has relation *location* to collection *Location*;

Collection *Location* is either a city, country, or region, and has relation *city*, *country*, *region* to itself.

Now, I would like to query all users who belong to companies in Germany or EU.

```
SELECT from Users where Users.company.location.city.country.name="Germany";
SELECT from Users where Users.company.location.city.parent.name="Germany";
```

or

```
SELECT from Users where Users.company.location.city.country.region.name="europe";
SELECT from Users where Users.company.location.city.parent.parent.name="europe";
```

Assuming that *Location.name* is indexed, can I have the two queries above executed with *O(n)*, with *n* being the number of documents in *Location* (*O(1)* for graph traversal, *O(n)* for index scanning)?

Of course, I could just save *regionName* or *countryName* directly in *company*, as these cities and countries are in EU, unlike in ... other places, won't probably change, but what if... you know what I mean (kidding, what if I have other use cases which require constant update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to explain this [using the ArangoDB 2.8 Traversals](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Aql/GraphTraversals.html).

We Create these collections to match your shema using [arangosh](https://docs.arangodb.com/Arangosh/index.html):

```
db._create("countries")
db.countries.save({_key:"Germany", name: "Germany"})
db.countries.save({_key:"France", name: "France"})
db.countries.ensureHashIndex("name")

db._create("cities")
db.cities.save({_key: "Munich"})
db.cities.save({_key: "Toulouse")

db._create("company")
db.company.save({_key: "Siemens"})
db.company.save({_key: "Airbus"})

db._create("employees")
db.employees.save({lname: "Kraxlhuber", cname: "Xaver", _key: "user1"})
db.employees.save({lname: "Heilmann",  cname: "Vroni",  _key: "user2"})
db.employees.save({lname: "Leroy",  cname: "Marcel",  _key: "user3"})

db._createEdgeCollection("CityInCountry")
db._createEdgeCollection("CompanyIsInCity")
db._createEdgeCollection("WorksAtCompany")


db.CityInCountry.save("cities/Munich", "countries/Germany", {label: "beautiful South near the mountains"})
db.CityInCountry.save("cities/Toulouse", "countries/France", {label: "crowded city at the mediteranian Sea"})

db.CompanyIsInCity.save("company/Siemens", "cities/Munich", {label: "darfs ebbes gscheits sein? Oder..."})
db.CompanyIsInCity.save("company/Airbus", "cities/Toulouse", {label: "Big planes Ltd."})


db.WorksAtCompany.save("employees/user1", "company/Siemens", {employeeOfMonth: true})
db.WorksAtCompany.save("employees/user2", "company/Siemens", {veryDiligent: true})
db.WorksAtCompany.save("employees/user3", "company/Eurocopter", {veryDiligent: true})
```

In AQL we would write this query the other way around.
We start with the constant time `FILTER` on the indexed attribute `name` and start our traversals from there on.
Therefor we filter for the country "Germany":

```
db._explain("FOR country IN countries FILTER country.name == 'Germany' RETURN country ")
Query string:
 FOR country IN countries FILTER country.name == 'Germany' RETURN country 

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType        Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode      1   * ROOT
  6   IndexNode          1     - FOR country IN countries   /* hash index scan */
  5   ReturnNode         1       - RETURN country

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields       Ranges
  6   hash   countries    false    false        66.67 %   [ `name` ]   country.`name` == "Germany"

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   use-indexes
  2   remove-filter-covered-by-index
```

Now that we have our well filtered start node, we do a graph traversal in reverse direction. Since we know that `Employees` are exactly 3 steps away from the start Vertex, and we're not interested in the path, we only return the 3rd layer:

```
db._query("FOR country IN countries FILTER country.name == 'Germany' FOR v IN 3 INBOUND country CityInCountry, CompanyIsInCity, WorksAtCompany  RETURN v")

[ 
  { 
    "cname" : "Xaver", 
    "lname" : "Kraxlhuber", 
    "_id" : "employees/user1", 
    "_rev" : "1286703864570", 
    "_key" : "user1" 
  }, 
  { 
    "cname" : "Vroni", 
    "lname" : "Heilmann", 
    "_id" : "employees/user2", 
    "_rev" : "1286729095930", 
    "_key" : "user2" 
  } 
]
```

Some words about this queries performance:

- We locate Germany using a hash index is constant time -> **O(1)**
- Based on that we want to traverse *m* many paths where *m* is the number of employees in *Germany*; Each of them can be traversed in constant time.
  -> **O(m)** at this step.
- Return the result in constant time -> **O(1)**

  All combined we need **O(m)** where we expect *m* to be less than *n* (the number of employees) as used in your SQL-Traversal.

Comment: Oh, I get it, so I should change my mindset, instead of saying "get me a list of users whose city whose country is Germany", I should ask for "take a look at Germany, follow the paths until you get to users and get me that list".

Then what if I have more than 1 condition (sorry for the old mind set here)

   SELECT from Users where Users.company.location.city.country.name="Germany" and Users.department.parent.parent="Product development";

with "department" can be hierarchal (just like location), e.g. "Backend" -> "Web development" -> "Software development" -> "Product development"?

Comment: Is the "graph intersection" suitable for the above-described scenario, and is it O(m+n) where m is number if employees in Germany and n is the number of employees in "Product development" department? And is `GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS` the right function?

Comment: You can add [FILTER statements to the traversal part](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Aql/GraphTraversals.html#filter-examples) and would probably therefore want to filter for something like path.vertices[3].department == "product development" - or if that comes from another collection, you could first get that department with a `LET department=(FOR d IN departments FILTER name="Product Development" RETURN d)`

Comment: If you filter on `path.vertices[n].something` many queries will be able to prune all paths at length **n** if they do not match the filter condition. This affects the number traversed paths and reduces it. The Complexity of the filter depends on the comparison. A simple `==` will be constant time. If you use a more complex filter function, its complexity will be added. Path filters will only be executed on the exact traversal depth **n**. In General filters improve performance.  You can use `db.explain` for estimates.